# NSUserDefaults boolForKey strange behaviour on real phone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

My application is approved and ready to sale in appstore today. I downloaded it from appstore immediately but when I open my application there is no ads in my application. I dont understand anything.

In my code if user buy inapp item I set the value of userdefault to TRUE.

So when application starts Im checking this userdefaults. If it is TRUE I dont show any ads , if not I call ads api.

this is part of inapp purchasing area :

```
    if ([productId isEqualToString:@"dontshowads"])
    {   
            //user bought inapp item. so I must remove advertorials.

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"aldimi_lite_reklamikaldirma_099"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
```

and this is viewwillappear area :

```
    BOOL appin_reklamkaldirmaalindimi = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"aldimi_lite_reklamikaldirma_099"];

    NSLog(@"appin_reklamkaldirmaalindimi :%d",appin_reklamkaldirmaalindimi);

    if (!appin_reklamkaldirmaalindimi) 
    {
       NSLog(@"showing ads");
    }
    else {
       NSLog(@"no ads. user bought inapp item");
    }
```

When I run my application in simulator everything is fine. (I deleted it first in simulator and re build it)

Console gives this logs:

```
    appin_reklamkaldirmaalindimi : 0
    showing ads
```

When I run my application in my real phone everything is fine also. (I deleted it first in my phone and re build it)

Console gives this logs:

```
    appin_reklamkaldirmaalindimi : 0
    showing ads
```

But when I run my application which is downloaded from appstore everything is different.

Console gives this logs:

```
    appin_reklamkaldirmaalindimi : 0
    no ads. user bought inapp item
```

I tried to download and check the situation in my friends phone . Everything is the same. So it is not about my phone.

how can it possible ? I thought one hour and I cant find any explanation to this situation ...

Comment: did you try deleting and then installing the app again?

Comment: @shabzco hopefully has the right answer - your device is holding defaults from your testing, so it thinks you shouldn't be showing ads. Do you know anyone else who has downloaded it?

Comment: @jrturton I tried 5 times (deleting-reinstalling). And I called my friend. he came my house. we downloaded it from appstore. the situation is the same. (I had never run my applicaton on his phone before) and then I added his UDID to itunesconnect to run via xcode. After that I launched my application via xcode on his phone. everyting is fine as expected...

Comment: Just submit the app again. Maybe your app in AppStore is not the same as your code.

Comment: @tia I will do that. But I dont understand the problem. Console says : appin_reklamkaldirmaalindimi is FALSE namely 0, but in if-else statement how can it enter the else area ?

Comment: If set aside heap corruption problem, it will never enter the `else` part and that's why I believe your current code base does not reflect the actual released binary.

Comment: Did you 'Clean' your build before submitting? Also check the binary from the downloaded app for an entry of that BOOL type. Also use "YES" as the setting for a BOOL in objective-C not "TRUE"

Comment: @JacobFennell yes I cleaned. How can I check entry of that bool type from downloaded app ?

Comment: You can use something like http://www.iphonebackupextractor.com/ to pull out the plist in the Library directory from your phone backup.

Comment: by any chance, are you jailbroken. or have any tweaks installed that may bypass the in app purchasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation for such a weird phenomenon is that the code which you submitted to the App Store is in some way corrupted or different than the code which you tested by building off your computer.  The only way to fix this problem would be to resubmit your application to the App Store.

The only other possibility I can think of is that your app has some VERY poor and incorrect memory-access tendencies, such that part of your executable code or stack somehow gets over-written before running your ad logic.

Comment: I resubmitted my application to the store and the problem is gone. Thanks everybody.